# How to breakdown folder path in php

Tags: php

I am trying to break down a folder path

eg: `home/player/jay/profile/pictures`:

```
home
home/players
home/players/jay
home/players/jay/profile
home/players/jay/profile/pictures
```

i tryed using this but i cant get it to displaying right

```
$new_folders = explode("/","home/player/jay/profile/pictures");

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($new_folders); $i++) {
    for ($r = 0; $r < $i + 1; $r++) {
        $create_new_path .=  $new_folders[$r];
        if ($r != $i) {
            $create_new_path .= "/";
        }
    }

    //ftp_mkdir($conn_id, "httpdocs/user_images/".$create_new_path);
    //ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, "httpdocs/user_images/".$create_new_path);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$breakdown = array();
$dirs = explode('/', 'home/player/jay/profile/pictures');
$path = '';
foreach($dirs as $dir) {
    $path .= ($path !== '' ? '/' : '') . $dir;
    $breakdown[] = $path;
}
// result is in $breakdown
```